# Open .SVC in web browser

Tags: wcf, svc

I have been given a URI for a WCF web service (something like *http://some_uri:portnumber/someservice/service.svc*) but I cannot open it via a web browser or postman. I tried to open it with cURL but nothing happened either. Is there a certain wat to open .svc file on ubuntu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can open this URI by web browser:

[image]

You can also open this URI through postman:

[image]

**We can use svcutil to generate proxy classes to call the service. Please make sure that your WCF service is successfully deployed to IIS.**

Feel free to let me know if the problem persists.